# Does jQuery have a more restrictive :contains() - an exact match version?

Tags: jquery

I have a list with values 1 thru 16, as

```
 <li>1</li>
 <li>2</li> ....
 <li>10</li>
```

And I want to add a class based on the text value.  I tried this

```
$('#IDul_WeekSelector li:contains("1")').addClass('active');
```

The problem is that I get hits on both 1 and 10. Is there an exact match version of this? I looked a the other content filters available and I didn't see one. A regular expression might look like this: `/^1$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1st approach

You can use the attribute selector by taking advantage of the `data-*` attribute for then doing the following:

*(Of course it means that you will need to change your `HTML` just a bit to include the `data` attribute)*

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
  var num = 1;
  
  $('#IDul_WeekSelector li[data-value="' + num + '"]').addClass('active');

});
```

```css
.active {
  font-weight: bold; 
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="IDul_WeekSelector">
  <li data-value="1">1</li>
  <li data-value="2">2</li>
  <li data-value="3">3</li>
  <li data-value="4">4</li>
  <li data-value="5">5</li>
  <li data-value="6">6</li>
  <li data-value="7">7</li>
  <li data-value="8">8</li>
  <li data-value="9">9</li>
  <li data-value="10">10</li>
  <li data-value="11">11</li>
  <li data-value="12">12</li>
  <li data-value="13">13</li>
  <li data-value="14">14</li>
  <li data-value="15">15</li>
  <li data-value="16">16</li>
</div>
```

---

### 2nd approach

If you can't edit the `HTML`, then you can use the [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) function and add your `CSS` class at that point:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 
  var num = 1, 
      li = $('#IDul_WeekSelector li');
  
  li = li.filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() == num;
  });
  
  li.addClass('active');
  
});
```

```css
.active {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="IDul_WeekSelector">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is there an exact match version of [the `:contains()` selector]?

No, there's nothing in the default [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/), so you'll either have to create your own selector, or use [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter) with a custom function. Neither are particularly difficult.

An example using `.filter` would be:

```
var test = '1';
$(...).filter(function () {
  return $(this).text() === test;
});
```

Comment: I suppose I could just collect the text and take a look before I execute.  Thanks.   Hope you don't mind.  I'll let this sit for awhile.  Thanks again.